# Sums for certain colums and whole dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I want to analyze meteorological  data and find out how often a station (Xn) exceeds a certain treshold per year and the same for the whole data frame (so i get one value per year).
I tried a few things with Aggregate and Dplyr, but it doesn´t really work.

So first I give you my Data Frame (It´s just a dummy DF, the original one has about 80 colums and 10000 rows):

```
set.seed(123)
df1<-data.frame(replicate(6,sample(0:200,1500,rep=TRUE)))
date_df1<-seq(as.Date("1995-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 1500)
test_sto<-cbind(date_df1, df1)
test_sto$date_df1<-as.Date(test_sto$date_df1)
test_sto<-test_sto%>%    dplyr::mutate(     year = lubridate::year(date_df1), 
                                    month = lubridate::month(date_df1),
                                    day = lubridate::day(date_df1))

     date_df1  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6 year month day
1 1995-01-01 158 149  51 136  70 140 1995     1   1
2 1995-01-02 178 135 134 109  38 144 1995     1   2
3 1995-01-03  13  64  70 148 177 130 1995     1   3
```

So first, I tried it with the aggregate function, this gives me the following result:

```
aggregate.data.frame(x=test_sto[2:7] > 120, by = list(test_sto$year), FUN = sum, na.rm=TRUE )

 Group.1  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6
1    1995 143 141 159 152 147 144
2    1996 153 141 148 153 160 165
3    1997 148 126 150 149 139 153
```

This works for each station, but how do i get exceeds per year for the whole data frame?

I tried the following

```
aggregate.data.frame(x=test_sto[2:7] > 120, by = list(test_sto$year), FUN = colSums(test_sto[2:7] > 120, na.rm = TRUE), na.rm=TRUE )
```

But this obviously doesn´t work, but i can´t figure it out how to get something like a colSums into this function.

My second approach was with dplyr, but here i´am struggeling with the syntax i think:

```
test_sto %>% group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs((colSums(test_sto[2:7] > 120, na.rm=TRUE))))

   year date_df1    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6 month   day
   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  1995      601   601   601   601   601   601   601   601   601
 2  1995      576   576   576   576   576   576   576   576   576
 3  1995      610   610   610   610   610   610   610   610   610
 4  1995      622   622   622   622   622   622   622   622   622
 5  1995      610   610   610   610   610   610   610   610   610
 6  1995      616   616   616   616   616   616   616   616   616
 7  1996      601   601   601   601   601   601   601   601   601
 8  1996      576   576   576   576   576   576   576   576   576
 9  1996      610   610   610   610   610   610   610   610   610
10  1996      622   622   622   622   622   622   622   622   622
```

Theres the same value for each column, which is definitely incorrect, but i can´t find my mistake. And also the years are incorrect somehow.
The goal here is the same as above, how often does a station exceeds the treshold and the same for the whole data frame.

Comment: hint: without `set.seed()`, your output will not be reproducible

Comment: where do i have to put set.seed()? like: df1<- set.seed(data.frame(replicate...)?

Comment: in a separate line, above `df1<-data.frame(replicate(6,sample(0:200,1500,rep=TRUE)))`. This makes sure the results of the `sample()` function will always be the same, so everybody can try to produce anwers that are the same as your desired output.

Comment: add the line `set.seed(123)`, and up[date your desired output accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyverse` you could do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

test_sto %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("X"), ~sum(. > 120)))
```

**Output**

```
   year    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1  1995   143   141   159   152   147   144
2  1996   153   141   148   153   160   165
3  1997   148   126   150   149   139   153
4  1998   144   150   138   152   145   138
5  1999    13    18    15    16    19    16
```

And for all stations each year, just `group_by(year)` after putting into long form with `pivot_longer`:

```
test_sto %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("X")) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(gtr_120 = sum(value > 120))
```

**Output**

```
   year gtr_120
  <dbl>   <int>
1  1995     886
2  1996     920
3  1997     865
4  1998     867
5  1999      97
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I believe this is what you are looking for?

```
library(data.table)
# make it a data.table
setDT(test_sto)

# part 1: >120 by year
test_sto[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x > 120)), 
           by = .(year), 
           .SDcols = patterns("^X")]
#    year  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6
# 1: 1995 143 141 159 152 147 144
# 2: 1996 153 141 148 153 160 165
# 3: 1997 148 126 150 149 139 153
# 4: 1998 144 150 138 152 145 138
# 5: 1999  13  18  15  16  19  16

# part 2: totals >120 by station over all years
test_sto[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x > 120)), 
         .SDcols = patterns("^X")]
#     X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6
# 1: 601 576 610 622 610 616
```

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, the firs part looks good.

But for part 2 i´m looking for the treshold exceeds per year for the whole data frame, like one value per year.
sum(colSums(test_sto[2:7] > 120, na.rm=TRUE))-> with this i get the number of treshold exceeds for every station combined, but i need it per year